# How to flip specific parts of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to flip certain parts of a matrix. I can explain better by example. Let's say that I have a matrix

```
M = [  1    3   6;      
       1    2   4;      
       1    7   1;      
       2    9   0;      
       2    8   3;      
       2    4   2;      
       2    3   1;      
       3    6   5;      
       3    4   5;      
       3    1   9;      
       4    2   4;  
       4    8   6 ]
```

What I'd like to do here is take any rows with an even number in the first column, and flip the third column elements. The end result would look like this:

```
   1    3   6       
   1    2   4       
   1    7   1       
   2    9   1   *   
   2    8   2   *   
   2    4   3   *   
   2    3   0   *   
   3    6   5       
   3    4   5       
   3    1   9       
   4    2   6   *
   4    8   4   *
```

Note the rows marked with a star have had the elements of the third column flipped upside-down. The problem I'm having is going through each row like in a for-loop you cannot flip an entire set of rows.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please post the code you have been using thus far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another time [**`accumarray`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is the way to go:

```
A =[ 1    3   6 ;       
     1    2   4 ;      
     1    7   1 ;       
     2    9   0 ;       
     2    8   3 ;       
     2    4   2 ;       
     2    3   1 ;       
     3    6   5 ;      
     3    4   5 ;       
     3    1   9 ;       
     4    2   4 ;   
     4    8   6 ] 

C = accumarray(A(:,1),A(:,3),[],@(x) {flipud(x)} );  %// get groups according to
                                                     %// first column and flip it
C = vertcat(C{:});                                   %// cell array returned, 
                                                     %// transform to matrix

mask = ~mod(A(:,1),2);  %// mask for even numbers                     
A(mask,3) = C(mask);    %// replace masked values of 3rd column with flipped ones
```

returns:

```
A =

     1     3     6
     1     2     4
     1     7     1
     2     9     1
     2     8     2
     2     4     3
     2     3     0
     3     6     5
     3     4     5
     3     1     9
     4     2     6
     4     8     4
```

---

Certainly slower, but just for fun in two lines:

```
C = accumarray(A(:,1),A(:,3),[],@(x) {flipud(x)} );
A(~mod(A(:,1),2),3) = getfield( vertcat(C{:}), {~mod(A(:,1),2)});
%// well no, I won't explain it...
```

---

Edit:  I assumed your first column just contains integers!

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am still learning Matlab so it'll take me a while to understand and go through your process, but I'm certainly going to study it! :)

Comment: @Nevermore I added some explanations.

Comment: Thanks again that definitely helps! My first column does indeed only contain integers :P

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you break the problem down into stages, something like so:

1. Identify blocks you wish to flip
2. Extract them
3. Flip them
4. Replace them

You can identify a set of even numbers using the `unique` and `mod` functions, then use a for loop over them and use logical indexing to pull/replace the blocks.

Comment: That's definitely a good way to look at it, break it down... I will give it another go with this in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this

```
a = magic(5); % Some data in a 5x5 matrix
b = 1:numel(a); % Indices of <a>
```

Rearrange b however you want, then do `a=a(b)` to reassign a based on the reassigned indices of b. For example, the following code

```
disp(a(b));
```

would just return the elements of a in their original order. For your application this code should work:

```
a = <your matrix data>
b = 1:numel(a);
b = [b(1:27) fliplr(b(28:31)) b(32:34) fliplr(b(35:36))] % Change this part
a = reshape(a(b),size(a))
```

You should change b based on whatever you need it to do.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to implement this as well :)